# RedirectTo methode in loginController in laravel don't work

Tags: php, laravel, http-redirect

i wanna to redirect each user to his page deppends on  his role 
and this is the redirectTo() that i have made in loginController ,
each login they redirect me to home page and they don't access to redirectTo methode

```
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->roles;
        $role="codingTeam";
        switch($role){
            case 'codingTeam':
                return '/codingTeam';
            break;
            case 'admin':
                return '/admin';
            break;
            case 'secretariat':
                return '/secretariat';
            break;
            default:
                return 'auth/login';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In LoginController u have `protected $redirectTo` property.
If u want to make `redirect()` first u need to define your `redirectTo` property,

```
    private function redirectTo()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->roles;
        $role="codingTeam";
        switch($role){
            case 'codingTeam':
                $this->redirectTo = '/codingTeam';
            break;
            case 'admin':
                $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
            break;
            case 'secretariat':
                $this->redirectTo = '/secretariat';
            break;
            default:
                $this->redirectTo = 'auth/login';
            break;
        }
    }
```

and after in action use call `$this->redirectTo()` and after `return redirect($this->redirectPath())`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private function redirectTo()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->roles;
        $role="codingTeam";
        switch($role){
            case 'codingTeam':
               return redirect('/codingTeam') ;
            break;
            case 'admin':
              return redirect('/admin');
            break;
            case 'secretariat':
                return redirect('/secretariat');
            break;
            default:
                return redirect('auth/login');
            break;
        }
    }
```